# Swift: When to choose 'class' over 'actor'?

Tags: ios, swift

Consider some common use cases for `class`:

- Mutable objects that can be shared throughout the app like a `User`
- Editable models like a `Recipe`
- Shared global state like an `ImageCache`

Up until now we've been responsible for synchronizing access to these objects manually. With Swift 5.5 this can now be handled automatically, with potential misuse caught by the compiler. So it seems like each of these examples is a prime candidate for `actor`.

So, when might we choose to use `class` instead?

The main limitation of `actor` seems to be that it doesn't support inheritance, so I guess we could say that only `final` classes can be migrated.

Are there any other reasons to use `class` instead of `actor` for all reference types?

Comment: "only final classes can be migrated" And only classes that have no superclass. If you are sharing access to a class instance merely because you need to hand out references to a reference type object, then if you have multiple threads, changing to an actor is a great idea. If all your code runs on the main thread, there's no point.